# Select row A if a condition satisfies else select row B for each group

Tags: sql, mariadb, window-functions

We have 2 tables, bookings and docs

bookings

```
booking_id    |  name    
100           |  "Val1"  
101           |  "Val5"  
102           |  "Val6"
```

docs

```
doc_id  |  booking_id  |  doc_type_id  
6       |  100         | 1
7       |  100         | 2
8       |  101         | 1
9       |  101         | 2
10      |  101         | 2
```

We need the result like this:

```
booking_id | doc_id
100        | 7
101        | 10
```

Essentially, we are trying to get the latest record of doc per booking, but if doc_type_id 2 is present, select the latest record of doc type 2 else select latest record of doc_type_id 1.

Is this possible to achieve with a performance friendly query as we need to apply this in a very huge query?

Comment: I am using 10.5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `FIRST_VALUE()` window function by sorting properly the rows for each `booking_id` so that the rows with `doc_type_id = 2` are returned first:

```
SELECT DISTINCT booking_id,  
       FIRST_VALUE(doc_id) OVER (PARTITION BY booking_id ORDER BY doc_type_id = 2 DESC, doc_id DESC) rn
FROM docs;
```

If you want full rows returned then you could use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SELECT booking_id, doc_id, doc_type_id  
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY booking_id ORDER BY doc_type_id = 2 DESC, doc_id DESC) rn
  FROM docs
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: I did as below for multiple columns so that i can avoid subquery hoping for performance
SELECT DISTINCT booking_id,  
       FIRST_VALUE(doc_id) OVER (W) doc_id,
       FIRST_VALUE(doc_type_id) OVER (W) doc_type_id
FROM docs
WINDOW W AS (PARTITION BY booking_id ORDER BY doc_type_id = 2 DESC, doc_id DESC);